# Анимация начинается при старте игры и не заканчивается

Tags: c#, unity3d, анимация

Есть ошибка: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
UnitSkin.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/UnitSkin.cs:19)

Персонаж двигается как надо, но анимация движения не реагирует на команды, проигрывается со старта

Помогите указать на экземпляр объекта

Вот код

```c#
[RequireComponent(typeof(UnitMovement))]

    public class PlayerInput : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] private string _moveAxis = "Horizontal";
        [SerializeField] private KeyCode _jumpKey = KeyCode.UpArrow;
        private UnitMovement _target;

        private void Start ()
        {
            _target = GetComponent<UnitMovement>();
        }

        private void Update ()
        {
            _target.MoveInput = Input.GetAxis(_moveAxis);
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(_jumpKey))
                _target.TryJump();
        }
        }
```

```c#
    [RequireComponent(typeof(UnitMovement))]

    public class PlayerInput : MonoBehaviour
    {
    [SerializeField] private string _moveAxis = "Horizontal";
    [SerializeField] private KeyCode _jumpKey = KeyCode.UpArrow;
    private UnitMovement _target;

    private void Start ()
    {
        _target = GetComponent<UnitMovement>();
    }

    private void Update ()
    {
        _target.MoveInput = Input.GetAxis(_moveAxis);
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(_jumpKey))
            _target.TryJump();
    }
    }
```

```c#
   [RequireComponent(typeof(UnitMovement), typeof(Animator))]
    public class UnitSkin : MonoBehaviour 
    {
    private Animator _animator;
    private UnitMovement _unit;

    void Update()
    {
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
    {
        _animator.SetBool("isJump", true);
    }
    else
    {
        _animator.SetBool("isJump", false);
    }
    
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        _animator.SetBool("isWalk", true);
    }
    else
    {
        _animator.SetBool("isWalk", false);
    }

    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        _animator.SetBool("isWalk", true);
    }
    else
    {
        _animator.SetBool("isWalk", false);
    }
    }
    }
```

```c#
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]
public class UnitMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] private float _moveSpeed = 6;
[SerializeField] private float _jumpForce = 7;
private Rigidbody2D _body;
[SerializeField] private GroundCheck _ground;

public float MoveInput { get; set; }
public bool OnGround => _ground.OnGround;

private void Start ()
{
    _body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

private void FixedUpdate ()
{
    _body.velocity = new Vector2(_moveSpeed*MoveInput, _body.velocity.y);
}

public void TryJump ()
{
    if (_ground.OnGround)
        _body.velocity = new Vector2(0, _jumpForce);
}
}
```

```c#
public class GroundCheck : MonoBehaviour 
{
[SerializeField] private float _radius;
[SerializeField] private LayerMask _whatIsGround;

public bool OnGround { get; private set; }

private void FixedUpdate ()
{
    OnGround = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(transform.position, _radius, _whatIsGround);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У класса `UnitSkin` нет ссылки на `Animator`. Добавьте в этом классе перед `Update`

```
private void Awake()
{
   _animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
}
```